# csvkit: for csv to Table, how do you preserve quoted strings when

Tags: python, csv, csvkit

When using csvkit, I'm having trouble keeping character data from getting transformed to numeric data.
For the example below, my first column gets transformed into an 'int'

Data: (test.csv)

```
"BG_ID_10","DisSens_2010","PrivateNeglect_2010"
"250250001001",0.506632168908,0.363523524561
"250250001004",0.346632168908,0.352456136352
```

Code snippet:

```
from csvkit import sql as csvkit_sql
from csvkit import table
from csv import QUOTE_NONNUMERIC

fh = open('test.csv', 'rb')

csv_table = table.Table.from_csv(f=fh,\
                        name='tname',\
                        delimiter=',',\
                        quotechar='"',\
                        snifflimit=0,\
                        )

for col in csv_table:
    print col.name, col.type
```

Output:

```
BG_ID_10 <type 'int'>
DisSens_2010 <type 'float'>
PrivateNeglect_2010 <type 'float'>
```

I have a working hack but would appreciate any help better parameters for the "from_csv" or alternative suggestions.  (Note, after this step, the csvkit commands are used for generating Postgres create table statements.)

Working Hack:

```
char_col = csv_table[0] # get first column
char_col.type = unicode # change type
for idx, val in enumerate(char_col):  # force to unicode
    char_col[idx] = u'%s' % val
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `infer_types=False` to your `from_csv` call. All types will become `unicode`:

```
BG_ID_10 <type 'unicode'>
DisSens_2010 <type 'unicode'>
PrivateNeglect_2010 <type 'unicode'>
```

But there's currently no way to specify the type without [building Columns yourself](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit/blob/daf33357c4e3fc40ee67939d612930bfd90ce51f/csvkit/table.py#L198).

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I'll build the column myself.  (infer_types at the table level will help with another, unrelated piece of code:)